# Orocommerce Sitemap generated but not in example.com/sitemap

Tags: sitemap, orocommerce

I have a problem with my sitemap.
When the cron is executed, I have .xml.gz files in public/media/sitemaps/ folder but nothing under [www.mywebsite.com/sitemaps/](http://www.mywebsite.com/sitemaps/)

BUT! I have a robot.txt on this URL [www.mywebsite.com/robots.txt](http://www.mywebsite.com/robots.txt)

Does everyone know why ?

Thank you

I tried to run the cron manually.
nothing in logs